# 2 degree multi variable curve fit

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I am working on my grad-school project where I have an equation something like this-

```
fos=f(x,y)= a1+a2*x+a3*x^2+a4*y+a5*y^2
```

I have values of `fos[]`, and `array[[x],[y]]`.
I need to know the method to get those coefficient value using numpy or scipy/scikit. I tried using PolynomialFeature in scikit but couldn't get a proper method to feed my given equation and calculate values based on those data.

Comment: Does it need to be numpy/scipy? It's always possible to use the algorithms of tensorflow to fit data. I tried a 2D Gaussian with it and it worked very well

Comment: Well, my whole project is in python and I wanted to implement some small workaround code, its just a part of my project

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to your question. Basically, fitting a function like this is pretty simple with numpy. I have commented the code below heavily. You can see that in the first 4 code lines (excluding comment and empty lines) I just make the dataset I want to fit, fit Z by using X and Y. Here Z = fos=f(x,y).

The first important line for you fitting your dataset once you have loaded it would be `XY = ...` After this there is only one more line to find your coefficients and then the rest is just to print them out.

```
import numpy as np

# in these 4 lines I just create a some data
# You have your own so you can ignore them
# we have x and y and the z. z is f(x,y)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 20), np.linspace(0, 1, 20), copy=False)
X = X.flatten()
Y = Y.flatten()
Z = (X**2 + Y**2 + np.random.rand(*X.shape)*0.01).flatten()

# we want to make the function something like a1+a2*x+a3*x^2+a4*y+a5*y^2
# we will first make an array of our known variables
# we want a array of 1, x, x**2, y, y**2
# after we have this we can fit it linearly to get the coefficients a_n

XY = np.array([np.ones(X.shape), X, Y, X**2, Y, Y**2]).T

# here is where we actually fit the coefficients
coeff,_,_,_ = np.linalg.lstsq(XY, Z)

for i in range(len(coeff)):
    print('a{} = {}'.format(i, coeff[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Closely following [this code](https://gist.github.com/silgon/24b56f8ae857ff4ab397) I got the following:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5):
    return a1+a2*x[0]+a3*x[0]**2+a4*x[1]+a5*x[1]**2

limits = [-10, 10, -10, 10]  # [x1_min, x1_max, x2_min, x2_max]
side_x = np.linspace(limits[0], limits[1], 100)
side_y = np.linspace(limits[2], limits[3], 100)
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(side_x, side_y)
size = X1.shape
X1_1d = X1.reshape((1, np.prod(size)))
X2_1d = X2.reshape((1, np.prod(size)))


xdata = np.vstack((X1_1d, X2_1d))

#Here I create some sample data
original = (1,2,3,4,5)
z = f(xdata, *original)
Z = z.reshape(size)
z_noise = z + .2*np.random.randn(len(z))
Z_noise = z_noise.reshape(size)

#For z_noise you have to plug in your data here
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, xdata, z_noise)
print("fitted: {}".format(popt))
z_fit = f(xdata, *popt)
Z_fit = z_fit.reshape(size)

#Plotting
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title("Sample data")
plt.pcolormesh(X1, X2, Z_noise)
plt.axis(limits)
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.title("Fitted Function")
plt.pcolormesh(X1, X2, Z_fit)
plt.axis(limits)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

First I define the function in the way you posted it (assuming that by `^` you meant `**`). Then I set limits for x and y axis (you will have to replace them with your own limits).

Now to make the fit work, we have to put your x/y data into one vector, which is what the code block until the first comment does. After the comment I create sample data, which you don't need as you have your own. The sample data is named `z_noise` (small z!) which you will have to reshape to a 1D vector. After all that I can just call `curve_fit` to get the parameters that match `z_noise` best.

I let the part with creating sample data in, so that this is easily testable and again: Most of this code is from [here](https://gist.github.com/silgon/24b56f8ae857ff4ab397)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will implement it asap

Comment: please don't forget to upvote and accept if this answer solved your problems. Others need to know if the question is correctly answered or not